# Make child divs expand to fill parent div's width

Tags: html, css

I have three divs inside one div.

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child"> Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
<div class="child">Text</div>
</div>
```

I want the child divs to fill up the width of the parent (the combined width of the children should be the parent). However, this is not happening, I'm falling short. I think this is because the child divs are setting width based on their content.

How do I achieve what I want?

CSS-

```
.child {
    background: white;
    color: #a7a9ac;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-right: 1px;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: @faded-grey;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.parent {
    border-top: 1px;
    border-left: 0;
    border-bottom: 1;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: @faded-grey;
    border-right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0px;
    height: 80px;

}
```

Comment: Could you post the css that you are using?

Comment: There are many ways, but it depends on what you want. Do you want the _last_ child div to fill up any remaining space, after the contents determine their widths? Or do you want them to be evenly spaced, _i.e._ via `width: 33%`?

Comment: set CSS, tried width:33%, but it puts the divs above one an another

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you know there will always be three children, you can simply use:

```
.parent > .child {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}

.parent {
    overflow: auto; /*or whatever float wrapping technique you want to use*/
}
```

If you do not know how many children there are, you will need to use CSS tables, flexbox, or perhaps combine inline-blocks with text-align: justify.

Answer (score 11):

You can add these three properties to the `.child` CSS rule:

```
width:33%;
float:left;    
box-sizing: border-box;
```

The last line makes sure it will also work when you add borders, padding and margin to the boxes.

<kbd>**[ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/dBeNv/)**</kbd>

Ps: not directly related but there is also an error in the border-bottom for parent, corrected in fiddle above. When you use non-0 value you need to specify unit:

```
    border-bottom:1px;
```

Comment: Awesome sauce! With due respect to other answers, I think this is the best answer.

Comment: Make the middle one width 34%, otherwise you only fill 99% of the container.

Answer (score 7):

I needed for my solution to accommodate a variance in the number of elements for them to be completely responsive.

I discovered an interesting solution to this. It essentially displays like a table. Every element shares available width, and this also works for images very well:
http://jsfiddle.net/8Qa72/6/

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 400px;
}

.table .row {
    display: table-row;
}

.table .row .cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px;
}

.table .row .cell .contents {
    background: #444;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
}
```

Comment: Another interesting solution is to use `display: inline-block` try it, it saves lives sometimes ;-)

Comment: How? It doesn't evenly split the available width of the parent between the children. Can you show me in a JSFiddle?

Comment: You right, you must specify a percentage of the parent div for each child if you want something similar

I tryed a "dynamic" approch and a "fixed" approch
http://jsfiddle.net/dBeNv/40/

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised that no one suggested the css3 solution using flex namely:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  flex: 1;
}
```