# How to get divs to take up full width of parent?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to get the divs (Name & Guess)  to take up the full width of the parent container. No matter what I have tried they're only reaching 98% of the container. If I set each one to 50% they collapse and then one container is on top of the other. They're currently set to 49%. Any ideas?

[image]

```css
.guess-section {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

.guess-section article {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #E0E0E0;
  margin: 2%;
  /*padding: 15px;*/
}

.r-low,
.r-high {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.user-input {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 49%;
}

.user-input input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article class="set-challengers">
  <p>The Current Range is <span class="r-low">1</span> to <span class="r-high">100</span></p>
  <section class="challenger2">
    <h3>Challenger 2</h3>
    <div class="user-input">
      <label for="name">
      <span>Name</span></br>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="user-input">
      <label for="name">
      <span>Guess</span></br>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
    </label>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="challenger-buttons">
    <button class="submit">SUBMIT GUESS</button>
    <button class="reset">RESET GAME</button>
    <button class="clear">CLEAR GAME</button>
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: look into `box-sizing: border-box;`, but just don't implement it - understand it ;)

Comment: You should try it with `box-sizing: border-box`.

Comment: I do have ```box-sizing: border-box``` by the way, only posted the snippet regarding the specific html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make child divs expand to fill parent div's width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757086/make-child-divs-expand-to-fill-parent-divs-width)

Comment: Maybe look into using [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) for this.

Answer (score 3):

A helpful "reset" to include in most CSS is `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` because of the way the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) is designed. With the normal box model your padding and border are being added to the width of the element. So a "100% wide" element is really 100% + border + padding. `border-box` changes this so that width + border + padding is 100%.

Additionally: If you want to create two "exactly 50% wide" elements next to each other using `inline-block` then you need to use a negative margin or a trick to remove the whitespace between the elements in your markup. This is a small annoyance in HTML and you can see in the snippet below I fixed it by doing `</div` and then the final closing bracket on the next line `><div class="user-input">` A small amount of space gets placed between `inline-block` elements when there is whitespace between them in your markup.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.guess-section {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

.guess-section article {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 2px solid #E0E0E0;
    margin: 2%;
    /*padding: 15px;*/
}

.r-low, .r-high {
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.user-input {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50%;
}

.user-input input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article class="set-challengers">
        <p>The Current Range is <span class="r-low">1</span> to <span class="r-high">100</span></p>
        <section class="challenger2">
        <h3>Challenger 2</h3>
            <div class="user-input">
                <label for="name">
                <span>Name</span></br>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
                </label>
            </div
            ><div class="user-input">
                <label for="name">
                <span>Guess</span></br>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
                </label>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="challenger-buttons">
            <button class="submit">SUBMIT GUESS</button>
            <button class="reset">RESET GAME</button>
            <button class="clear">CLEAR GAME</button>
        </section>
</article>
```

Comment: I think the two `.user-input` `divs` need to be `50%`, the OP wants them side by side. Not stacked.

Comment: Yeah also added an edit for removing the whitespace to get perfectly 50/50 elements.

Comment: Nice. Didn't know about the `whitespace` trick in the `HTML`. +1

Answer (score 0):

`box-sizing:border-box` to the parent and it's children.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    .challenger2 {
      postion: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .user-input {
      float: left;
      border: 1px solid red;
      height: 100px;
      width: 50%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .user-input input {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```